# Geolocation with Latitude and Longitude as variables

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

thank you for taking a moment to help, if you can!

I am building a weather app and there's a page that I'm working on that needs to have latitude and longitude be updated frequently from a users phone.

i realize that there are two methods to do this...

1. getCurrentPosition()
2. watchPosition()

and I'm not really sure how to get the latitude/longitude into the request

Here is the code that I'm using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.aerisapi.com/wxblox/latest/aeris-wxblox.css">
<script src="https://cdn.aerisapi.com/wxblox/latest/aeris-wxblox.js"></script>

<!--// target DOM element where WeatherBlox will be rendered //-->
<div id="wxblox" class="aeris-wrapper"></div>

<script> 

// set Aeris account access keys
const aeris = new AerisWeather('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET');
aeris.on('ready', () => {

    // create desired WeatherBlox instance
    var view = new aeris.wxblox.layouts.local.Main('#wxblox', {
        obs: {
            advisories: {
                enabled: true
            },
            threats: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        nearby: {
            request: {
                limit: 4
            }
        },
        shortterm: {
            request: {
                limit: 3
            }
        },
        forecast: {
            type: "detailed"
        },
        maps: {
            animation: {
                enabled: true,
                autoplay: false,
                alwaysShowPast: false,
                alwaysShowFuture: false,
                from: -2,
                to: 0,
                duration: 2,
                endDelay: 1,
                intervals: 10
            },
            controls: {
                layers: [
                    {
                        value: "radar",
                        title: "Radar"
                    },{
                        value: "satellite",
                        title: "Satellite"
                    },{
                        value: "alerts",
                        title: "Advisories"
                    },{
                        value: "temperatures,clip-us-flat",
                        title: "Temps"
                    }
                ],
                regions: [
                    {
                        zoom: 7,
                        title: "Local"
                    },{
                        zoom: 5,
                        title: "Regional"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    // load data and render the view for a specific location
    view.load({
        p: "Latitude, Longitude"
    });
    
});

</script>
```

At the bottom where it says p:"Latitude, Longitude" is where I would need the results of those geolocation methods, as variables, to be placed. Perhaps more clearly it should be "Users Latitude, Users Longitude"

The user opens the app and this is the first page that they will see.  This is a local weather conditions page which gets data from the closest weather observation point to the user.

IF I had to choose between the two methods, I would probably prefer watchPosition since it keeps up with the users location as they move.

Thank you for any help you may offer

Sincerely,

Justin

Comment: If you put their location here, it won't update when they move.

Comment: You need to update the weather location in the callback function of `watchPosition`.

Comment: So is it better to use getCurrentPosition and just have the autorefresh enabled within the app?

Comment: I don't know anything about the `aeris` app. If it can get the location itself, you shouldn't need to do anything at all.

Comment: Well, I'm making an app.  This is just a way to access their data and display it in an html page.  I'm trying to get the location data through a phones gps...and have one of these geolocation methods provide the lat and long in the p:"latitude, longitude" section at the bottom

Comment: Getting the location from the phone is easy. You call `watchPosition()`, it calls your callback function when the location changes. The question is how you tell WeatherBlox to change the location of the view when the location changes.

Comment: Well do I have to do that if I have an autorefresh?  Just execute the whole thing again every 5 minutes or something?  I guess watchPosition isn't the best fit?  i mean,it would be cool to have the app automatically adjust to new weather data as you move into a new location...but I really have no clue how to do that.

Comment: As I said, I don't know the functionality of the Aeris WeatherBlox. I tried looking in the documentation, but I couldn't find anything about changing the location. If you can't find this, I guess you have to recreate it whenever the location changes.

Comment: Ok gotcha.  Well, how can I get the latitude and longitude variables into the P: at the end?  Any chance you can help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Call `view.load()` in the success callback of `getCurrentPosition()`.

```
// load data and render the view for a specific location
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
    console.log(`Showing weather for lat ${pos.coords.latitude}, long ${pos.coords.longitude}`);
    view.load({p: `${pos.coords.latitude}, ${pos.coords.longitude}`});
}, err => console.log(`Geolocation error: ${err.message}`));
```

Full code:

```js
// set Aeris account access keys
const aeris = new AerisWeather('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET');
aeris.on('ready', () => {

  // create desired WeatherBlox instance
  var view = new aeris.wxblox.layouts.local.Main('#wxblox', {
    obs: {
      advisories: {
        enabled: true
      },
      threats: {
        enabled: true
      }
    },
    nearby: {
      request: {
        limit: 4
      }
    },
    shortterm: {
      request: {
        limit: 3
      }
    },
    forecast: {
      type: "detailed"
    },
    maps: {
      animation: {
        enabled: true,
        autoplay: false,
        alwaysShowPast: false,
        alwaysShowFuture: false,
        from: -2,
        to: 0,
        duration: 2,
        endDelay: 1,
        intervals: 10
      },
      controls: {
        layers: [{
          value: "radar",
          title: "Radar"
        }, {
          value: "satellite",
          title: "Satellite"
        }, {
          value: "alerts",
          title: "Advisories"
        }, {
          value: "temperatures,clip-us-flat",
          title: "Temps"
        }],
        regions: [{
          zoom: 7,
          title: "Local"
        }, {
          zoom: 5,
          title: "Regional"
        }]
      }
    }
  });

  console.log("Getting Geolocation");
  // load data and render the view for a specific location
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
    console.log(`Showing weather for lat ${pos.coords.latitude}, long ${pos.coords.longitude}`);
    view.load({
      p: `${pos.coords.latitude}, ${pos.coords.longitude}`
    });
  }, err => console.log(`Geolocation error: ${err.message}`));

});
```